# I want to test apk on simulator also, how to include simulator(intel) architecture to build process

Tags: android, flutter, x86, apk, simulator

We want to test apk files on simulators. But the problem is we cannot install it on simulators running on intel machines. How to include intel(x86) architecture to build process.

Answer (score 0):

To test on Intel Core(x86), you need to build on Intel Core (x86).m1 cores mac is not possible.

Comment: do you know about cross compilation?